# Check if format of a .txt file is valid in C?

Tags: c, validation

I'm trying to make sure that the .txt file I'm using is of a certain format, so for example 4 characters by 4 characters. As an example I have example1.txt which could look something like this:

```
 ....
 ....
 ....
 ....
```

I use `fscanf()` to read in the file and store it in an array like so `./myprogam < example1.txt`:

```
 char myArray[4][4] = {""};
 for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
         fscanf(stdin, "%c ", &myArray[i][j]);
     }
 }
```

So I thought I could create a function that checks if each cell of `myArray` has been filled with a character or not, and if it hasn't, then it's not a valid format, like so:

```
checkArray(char myArray) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (myArray[i][j] == '\0') return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This seems to be work, but I think there is probably a 'better' way to do this?

Comment: What if the lines happens to be longer than expected? Or there are more lines than expected? Or it doesn't end with a newline? Your code doesn't check for that. For simple files like your 4x4 file it's not really hard to check its validity, but if you have more of a free-format file, then it's suddenly becomes harder. *How* much harder depends on the file format, advanced formats might need a full C-like parser, while others can keep it within `scanf` (and family).

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that checking input file validity depends on the actual input file format, and every format needs different validation with different complexity.

Comment: Okay, so how should I check it's a valid format? I didn't think about if the lines are longer than expected. I only need to know if the file is 4 characters by 4 characters, and if it's not, then reject it.

Comment: Your `checkArray(char myArray)` function looks suspicious, you should pass the entire array as parameter, not a `char`. Something like `int checkArray(char **myArray)` (also do not forget to add the type of its return value - in your case it is an `int`).

Comment: I just added it as an example, it's not the actual code I'm using. As Joachim already pointed out, it doesn't work for all cases anyway, so do you have an idea how I could confirm the file is 4 characters by 4 characters?

Comment: regarding this line: ` char myArray[4][4] = {""};`   your trying to set characters, not pointer to strings, so the line should be: ` char myArray[4][4] = {'\0'};`

Comment: regarding this line: `checkArray(char myArray) {`   you need to pass in a 4x4 array of character, so the line should be: `checkArray(char myArray[][4]) {` which actually gives you a pointer to the right kind of array

Comment: the posted code is littered with 'magic' numbers.. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, maintain. Suggest: using `#define MAX_ROWS (4)` and `#define MAX_COLS (4)`  then using those values throughout the code.

Comment: the function `checkArray()`  would be much more flexible if written with a signature of: `int checkArray( size_t numRows, size_t numCols, char myArray[][numCols] )`  Then use the passed parameters `numRows` and `numCols` rather than the hard coded values `4`.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, do not `assume` that things went exactly as planned.  Rather check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  in this instance: `if( 1 != fscanf( "%c ", &myArray[i][j] ) ) { // handle error }`  where 'handle error' could be: `perror( "fscanf for array entry failed due to: "); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`  read the man pages for `exit` and for `fscanf` and `perror` for all the details.

Comment: @user362949 this is all very useful, but it doesn't actually help me any further with regards to my question. I do everything you already suggested, the above is merely just an example to get my point across. Literally all I want to do is read a file like so: `./myprogram < input.txt` and make sure it's a file containing 4 characters by 4 characters.

Answer (score 0):

For starters I would use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read into a six-character buffer. That makes it very easy to see if a line is longer than four characters or not, because if the line is longer then the fifth character (element  at index 4) will *not* be a newline. Be careful with the last line though as then the fifth element might be the terminator if there's no ending newline.

To check if there's more than four lines, after reading four lines with `fgets` I would simply try to read another *single* character. If I don't get an end of file, then the file contains more than four lines.

Finally, if the actual contents of each line has to follow some special format, I would check that after I checked that the file itself was okay or not (the two paragraphs above). For this one needs to know what the actual contents would be.

Please note that this is only *one* way to check that a file contains a 4x4 matrix of characters. It's easy to extend to an XxY matrix, but if you have any other kind of format it won't work at all.

Comment: I have tried using `fgets`, but then that means that filling myArray goes wrong afterwards. I want to keep those two for loops, and check the validity while inside them, if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve this without the need of saving characters inside a multidimensional array by reading the content of the file line by line. Below is a possible implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int file_format(int lines, int value)
{
    if(lines == 4 && value == 1)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int number_of_lines = 0;
    int ok = 1;
    char *line = NULL;
    FILE *in;

    if((in = fopen("input.txt", "r")) == NULL) //checking if the file is opened
        printf("File could not be located.\n");
    else
    {
        line = malloc(256); //allocating memory for a 256 characters-long line
        while((fscanf(in, "%[^\n]", line)) == 1 && ok == 1) //reading a whole line
        {
            number_of_lines++;
            if(strlen(line) != 4)
                ok = 0;
            fseek(in, 1, SEEK_CUR); //advancing to the next line
        }
        if(file_format(number_of_lines, ok) == 1)
            printf("File has the required format.\n");
        else
            printf("File does not have the required format.\n");
        free(line);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, but I don't want to specify the file's name as you are doing with "input.txt", so how would I do this then?

Comment: Also, I need to put it in the array anyway, so I think it would be nicer if I checked the validity while also putting it in the array at the same time.

Comment: @Esoemah: simply write what is presented as a `main()` program as a function and pass the name of the file to be processed as the argument to the new function.  You can arrange to pass the file name to a program as one of the arguments in `int main(int argc, char **argv)`.  Since the example program does not actually use either `argc` or `argv`, it should really be defined as `int main(void)` or perhaps `int main()` — they're basically equivalent, but the explicit `void` is what I use.

Comment: Note that a `malloc()` for 256 bytes is not really necessary, and it is not sufficient either while you use `"%[^\n]"` rather than `"%255[^\n]"`.  The latter ensures that no buffer overflow occurs.  POSIX provides `"%m[^\n]"` for [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html), and also
[`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) for arbitrary length lines — both do the memory allocation for you.

Comment: I am opening the file like so: `./myprogram < input.txt`, so I don't know what the filename is.